# Are backerboards needed next to shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tiling, backer-board

I'm remodeling an old bathroom.
The old old will be replaced with a Re-bath walk in shower.
I'm now considering to tile the wall next to it.
This wall has the sink on it and one outlet.
Right now the wall is only painted.
My question is - do I need backerboard or not?
The walk- in shower will have glass doors.

Thank you!

Comment: For tiles you need backerboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need cement backer board for an area like this (a non-shower wall). Tiles are glued to painted drywall all the time (think kitchen backsplash). Check with your supplier about which adhesive to use for going onto drywall- some thinsets are OK but often what are called "Mastic" adhesives are used over drywall.

Answer (score 1):

You can put tile on drywall.

But that's choosing a relatively poor foundation for a very expensive (materials and labor) finish when a superior foundation (backer board) would be a trivial change in cost to the overall project.

Your call.